# Pandas copy value from row above

Tags: python, pandas

Got a panda's dataframe with below structure:

```
Index    Name  Value  Other
1          NaN  10      5
2           A   20      2
3               30      3
4               100     12
5          NaN  40      10
6           C   10      1
7               40      10
8               40      10
9               40      10
10         NaN  40      10
11          D   10      1
12         NaN  40      10

...
```

I need to copy a value from column Name in rows that have it to rows that are below it until it finds NaN or other value? So how do i approach a copying a name A to row 3,4? then C [row 6] copying to row 7,8,9... until NaN/SomeName?

so after running the code it should get a dataframe like it:

```
Index    Name  Value  Other
1          NaN  10      5
2           A   20      2
3           A   30      3
4           A   100     12
5          NaN  40      10
6           C   10      1
7           C   40      10
8           C   40      10
9           C   40      10
10         NaN  40      10
11          D   10      1
12         NaN  40      10
```

Comment: Sir did your query solved?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Just use `replace()`:

```
df=df.replace('nan',float('NaN'),regex=True)
#for converting string 'nan' to Actual NaN
df['Name']=df['Name'].replace('',method='ffill')
#for forward filling '' values
```

output:

```
Index    Name  Value  Other
1          NaN  10      5
2           A   20      2
3           A   30      3
4           A   100     12
5          NaN  40      10
6           C   10      1
7           C   40      10
8           C   40      10
9           C   40      10
10         NaN  40      10
11          D   10      1
12         NaN  40      10
```

Comment: @jezrael sir but in the dataset provided by op..op wants to remove `''` and forward fill values(sorry sir if i was wrong!!) of column 'Name'

Comment: Ya, hard to know what is values, if empty string it should worjking well

Comment: @NiewaszBiznes kindly check update **:)**